# jQuery Toggling an image

Tags: jquery

Since im currently still learning jQuery and am new to it i need a little bit of help cause im on a short deadline... What im trying to do is swap between two images when the image is clicked it should switch to the other and vice versa... Seems like it should be simple enough but for some reason its not working as intended... Heres my code:

**UPDATED CODE**

html/php

```
<div name='contractActions' style="float: right; width: 50px;">
    <input type="hidden" id="cId" value="<?= $contractId ?>" />
    <?
    if(mysql_result($result, $i,"IsHighlighted") == 0)
    {
        $imgIsHighlighted = _IMAGES . "highlighter_on.png";
        $altIsHighlighted = "Remove Highlight";
    }
    else
    {
        $imgIsHighlighted = _IMAGES . "highlighter_off.png";
        $altIsHighlighted = "Highlight";
    }
    ?>
    <span class="link-black"><a href="#" class="highlightAction">
        <img src="<?= $imgIsHighlighted ?>" border="0" alt="<?= $altIsHighlighted ?>" /></a>
    </span>
    <span class="link-black"><a href="#" class="declineAction">
        <img src="images/decline.png" border="0" alt="Decline" /></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".highlightAction").click(function() {
    var element = $(this).closest("div[name='contractActions']");
    var cId = $(element).find("#cId").val();
    var field = "IsHighlighted";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/contract_buttons.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: "contractId=" + cId + "&updateField=" + field,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $(element).find("a[class='highlightAction']").children("img").toggle(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/highlighter_off.png");
                $(this).attr("alt", "Remove Highlight");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/highlighter_on.png");
                $(this).attr("alt", "Highlight");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The code doesnt seem to work on the initial click afterwards however it toggles between them. Its as if the toggling doesnt activate until AFTER the first click **and occasionaly after the second click**. Any reasons as to why this might be happening? and a solution to this issue if possible thanks in advance!!

Comment: try reversing the functions... put the "Highlight" stuff on bottom and the "Remove Highlight" stuff on top

Comment: it has the same issue when i reverse it :(

Comment: This seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HWGQA/

Comment: is `images/highlighter_on.png` the default src value, because you would need to switch them around so that off is in the upper function, and on is in the latter

Comment: And I'm guessing that `element` is a reference/selector to an element.

Comment: @RobertPitt the default src changes between the two images depending on the value in the DB when it loads

Comment: @Jared Farrish Yes element points to the containing div of the image its being executed through ajax and is in the success section of the method

Comment: *depending on the value in the DB* - If this references a server's database, I imagine this could possibly be part of the problem.

Comment: @Jared Farrish i just tested the link you sent and it seems to work there i dont understand why mines doesnt when the code is the same pretty much... :(

Comment: @Jared Farrish Why would that cause an issue though it pulls the value from the DB on load and then on click executes the click function calling the ajax method and on success toggles between the images i dont think there should be an issue with that though... and if there was it shouldnt work at all but it does work on the second click just not the first which is the strange part... also as a note on the odd occasion it works on the 3rd click and not the 1st or 2nd

Comment: I would just say, overall you might want to post the code or process description about how this works. Also, you might change the toggle function to check what the current state is and show the opposite (you could do this with one function), thereby bypassing all this nonsense.

Comment: And (as far as 1st, 2nd, 3rd click), `.toggle()` seems to lag a little, so performance wise, you might be better off with another solution.

Comment: @Jared Farrish just updated the code, what other options are there to .toggle() that i might be able to use?

Comment: @JaredFarrish let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2040/discussion-between-lord-link-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I discussed it over chat the outcome was that well the code seems to be correct as it was working on the testing website: www.jsfiddle.net as stated by Jared Farrish. However for some reason it was giving "me" personally an issue, we couldnt find exactly why, but looked at another method of doing this as the .toggle() function seems to be slow... The other method would be through the use of classes, also instead of saving the highlight value in a DB it could be done using states which would also mean less hitting the server and DB speeding up processing time. Anyhow hope this helps if anyone comes around a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).children("img").toggle(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/highlighter_off.png");
    $(this).attr("alt", "Remove Highlight");
},
function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/highlighter_on.png");
    $(this).attr("alt", "Highlight");
});
```

Switch the functions around.